# How does simple use of the asynchronous copy functionality differ in Hopper vs Ampere?

Tags: asynchronous, cuda, nvidia, idioms

I understand that Hopper GPUs have a new piece of hardware named the "transfer memory accelerator". In [this GTC 2023 session](https://static.rainfocus.com/nvidia/gtcspring2023/sess/1665676654831001nA0X/supmat/S51119%20-%20Optimizing%20Applications%20for%20Hopper%20Architecture_1679465633416001FEzo.pdf), we get an example of how to use it:

```cuda
extern __shared__ int smem[];
namespace cg = cooperative_groups;
__shared__ cuda::barrier<cuda::thread_scope_block> barrier;
auto block = cg::this_thread_block();

if (block.thread_rank() == 0) {
    init(&barrier, block.size());
}

block.sync();

// Collectively issue asynchronous copy operation
cuda::memcpy_async(block, smem, gmem,
    block.size() * sizeof(int), // int/thread
    barrier); // Barrier

auto token = barrier.arrive();

//<independent work>

barrier.wait(std::move(token));
```

How would I write the "same" code on an Ampere GPU? Or - would the code look the same, and it's just the implementation of the `cooperative_groups` and `barrier` classes, and the `memcpy_async()`, which are different?

Comment: You can write the same code for cc7.0 devices and higher, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-data-copies).  The behavior under the hood will vary between 7.0, 8.0, and 9.0.

Answer (score 2):

By using `cuda::memcpy_async` in CUDA C++, you are taking advantage of the best acceleration your hardware offers: thanks to JIT (just-in-time) compilation, the CUDA driver will determine how to compile best your program at runtime depending on your GPU architecture.

You can see on this [Godbolt shared link](https://godbolt.org/z/vYG3cYz8s) what your compiled program looks like in SASS (NVIDIA GPUs low-level assembly) with Ampere and Hopper.